# Angular component in a recursive ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, recursion, components

I have a question about recursion of ng-template and getting the components which are produces by the ng-template, which looks will like this:

```
<template #recursion>
    <header>
        <item>
            <repeat template #recursion><repeat>
        </item>
    </header>
<template>
```

When I use @ContentChildren on the header you'll get a list of the items of the ng-content but when you use @ContentChildren on the item then you won't get a list of headers which is in the ng-content.

What I expected was that @ContentChildren on the items would return an list of headers which are produced by the ng-template.

Example of mine: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhzpw1)

How can i solve this? I have tried with a lot of different solution but it just doesn't work.

Thanks :)

Comment: A question should contain the essential parts directly instead of linking to an external resource.

Comment: thanks have updated the question and hope it does some clarification what my question is.

Comment: As far as I remember dynamically added components and directives are not found by `@ContentChild()`. `<ul-title ...><ul-item ...>...</ul-item></ul-title>` makes it work one level deep because they are statically added in the template. What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps using a shared service is a better way?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish a tree view with expanding items with headers in it. But why wouldn't components and directive found if they are dynamically added by the template but when it is dynamically added on some other way it would recognize.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically added on some other way". I don't think it works if they were dynamically added. If you add a component dynamically then the components inside that components template are still statically added to that component. With statically added I mean - written into the template of a component. In your example `<ul-title>` as parent and `<ul-item>` as child are added statically to the components template. The content of the template is added dynamically - according to my understanding of things.

Comment: What i meant was if I got an component `<ul-title>` with an 'ng-content' and in the 'ng-content'. When something triggers to add an `<ul-item>` in the ng-content container. It will be discovered from what I understand.

And if it's in the template then I would use @ViewChildren, but that doesn't work too.

Comment: So, what's the problem of using a shared service instead of accessing components directly? Usually this is the better approach anyway.

Comment: As I read your comment I understand what you meant by how the ng-template works and why it doesn't detect the added components.

Comment: I don't know if it is explicitly stated anywhere that it should find children or content added using a template. In my experience it doesn't, but I don't have deep knowledge in this area.

Comment: Oh about the shared service approach, I have though of that but it's not that elegant cause it's an extra `thing`. If you look at how the way it got to work.

Comment: I think a shared service would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: But then you need to have an extra service for components that interact each other when they can read the value of each other if it's in a template. Isn't that a lil bit overkill?

Comment: I don't think a service is overkill. It's usually the best solution if you don't have direct parent-child relation where you can use `[inputInChild]="fieldInParent"`

Comment: For example: `<ul-header> <ul-item ngFor='item in items'> <ul-header ngFor='header in items.header'> <ul-item ngFor='childItem in header.items'></ul-item> </ul-header> </ul-item> </ul-header>` 

And in the item and header you have some ngIf of the @contentchildren. 

It will work like this so what you want is to clean a bit code to make an recursive template and for that to make it work you'll have to make an service :/, that's what i mean by overkill

Comment: It's common that people consider a service overkill, but I can't see it this way. I prefer dumb components anyway and therefore a service is usually the preferred way of doing many things in Angular. A service is very lightweight. I don't get why people think it's overkill.